# Error Fetching Data in React Native with Laravel as a Back-End

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, laravel-5, postman

I am using laravel as my back-end and I've tested all the method and it works tho. I already test it using postman for my laravel as a backend and it works. But when I try it in react native it didnt work at all. I'm still new to react native.

**Here's my code for PinjamList.js in RN:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class PinjamList extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        pinjams: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    render() {
        return ({
            this.props.pinjams.map((pinjam) => {
                return ({pinjam.ketua_kegiatan} | {pinjam.lab})
            })
        });
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    pinjamList: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
    },
    pinjamtext: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
    }
});
```

**And this one is js file for fetching the data:**

```
const URI = 'http://localhost:8000';
export default {
    async fetchDataPinjam() {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(URI + '/api/pinjams');
            let responseJsonData = await response.json();
            return
            responseJsonData;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**And this one is the code for displaying the data on the homepage:**

```
<View> { this.state.pinjams.length > 0 
? <PinjamList pinjams={this.state.pinjams} /> 
: <Text>Tidak Ada Peminjaman</Text> } </View>
```

**But when I try to test it to make sure if its right, this error shown:**

> Network request failed
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\core\whatwg-fetch.js:504:29 in onerror
>   - node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172:43 in dispatchEvent
>   - ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing : the API what is the HTTP method ? 
Second thing : if the method is `get` please add screen shot about results from your browser or postman

Comment: I tried to use GET Method, and here's the screen shot of the postman output.
https://ibb.co/0VMQpPp

Comment: ooh , you cant access the api from `localhost` domain , you must change the host to your computer ip address, like that `http://192.168.1.200:8000` , and you phone must connect to the same network , I mean your computer and your phone must connect to same network

Comment: Thanks for your solution Mr.Ahmad, and It worked for me. But may I ask another question? So, I have to change the IP in my Laravel or its just in my React Native fetch data?. My phone and My computer Connected to the same network, but the data still didn't show up, even the error didn't appear anymore .. So sorry I asked a lot :') but I'm kind of new to this

Comment: `const URI = 'http://192.168.100.9:8000';
export default{
    async fetchDataPinjam(){
        try{
            let response = await fetch(URI + '/api/pinjams');
            let responseJsonData = await response.json();
            return responseJsonData;
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I already tried to run my laravel using my IP address like php artisan serve -host ip address and it works somehow on my postman, but when it comes to my front end ofc react native, it still didn't work.. I am so desperate so sorry to asked a lot of question

Comment: Are you use windows operation system ? because the windows change ip address of your computer , you should fixed  your ip address by windows configuration and use it always

Comment: This is an IP of my wifi which my phone and pc are connected with, thats why I am using the wifi ip address that my pc caught ... and yes I am using windows OS ,,

Comment: You should make an your ip address is fixed by network configuration in windows , because when turn off or restart your computer , windows automatically change the ip , you can fixed your ip by this video https://youtu.be/5iRp1Nug0PU if you use windows 10 , after that you can use this ip always in any application

Comment: I already tried to change my IP whenever I want to start the application again but it still didnt work or maybe it should be static IP?

Comment: if you use the application not inside the same network ( phone , computer )  the application not worked , because you can't access the ip of computer because your phone not connected on the same network , the solution you must have static ip address by buy server or shared host

Comment: I already change it to static IP and restart the network also change the url ip on my project, but still no progress

Comment: hmmm , the static ip address you must check with your internet provider to make it static not dynamic , but this way not good , the best choice it is buy a server or shared hosting and upload your laravel project (back end api code ) and your application hitting on this server , the pricing of shared hosting is very cheap , or VPS pricing started from 5 USD per month , if you want to buy server tell me to help you

Comment: Anyway, It's Fixed already,,... I got stuck because of missing expression somehow... so sorry ... and Thank you for helping me out

Comment: Good Luck Leony

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, It's Fixed already,,... I got stuck because of missing expression somehow... so sorry ... and Thank you for helping me out.
For those who are using their smartphone to compile the application, please do check the IP Address, make sure your Phone and Laptop are connected with the same network, and do multiple checking on your code if there is something wrong with your app...
THANK YOU -